# Jupyter Notebook transfer variable from one block to another

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipywidgets

Given the following Juypter Notebook Code(3.10.7):

Codeblock 1:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

sprints_widget = widgets.SelectMultiple(
    options=['0', '-1', '-2', '+1'],
    value=['0'],
    rows=4,
    description='Sprint',
    disabled=False
)

display(widgets.HBox([sprints_widget]))

def cycle_selection(changed):
    relative_sprint_cycles = [int(relative_cycle) for relative_cycle in changed["new"]]
    print(relative_sprint_cycles)

sprints_widget.observe(cycle_selection, names='value')
relative_sprint_cycles = [int(relative_cycle) for relative_cycle in sprints_widget.value]
```

This renders a nice multiseltion and also implements the `observe` method.
Selecting a new number from the dropdown now (e.g. -2) triggers observe method and the `relative_sprint_cycles` variable gets updated. This is also printed under the block

Now on the second codeblock:

```py
print(relative_sprint_cycles)
sprints_widget.value
```

Runing the second block, Estimation would be, that the output for the "-2" selection would be

```
[-2] # <-- this is not updated and still showing the default selection [0]
("-2",)
```

but the first value is not updated, only the widget.

What am i missing and how can i also update the variabel without running the first codeblock again?